# How to remove unused levels from model matrix

Tags: r, model.matrix

I created a model matrix. Some variables are categorial variables.
After filtering  the data some levels are not in the data set anymore.
How can i remove the unused levels?
Can i apply the factor function on the categorial variables ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the `droplevels` function in *base R*. Let ***x*** be your factor/ categorical variable:

```
x <- as.factor(c("cat", "dog","cat", "gator"))
x
# [1] cat   dog   cat   gator
# Levels: cat dog gator

# somewhere in analysis you removed the only entry for a level
x <- x[x!= "gator"]     
x
# [1] cat dog cat
# Levels: cat dog gator

droplevels(x)
# [1] cat dog cat
# Levels: cat dog
```

*Refer [droplevels R documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/droplevels.html) for more details.*